# Why doesn't this code compile?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to understand why does this code compile:

```
public class A {
}

public class B extends A {
  public B() {
  }
}
```

while this code doesn't:

```
public class A {
  public A(int n) {
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  public B() {
  }
}
```

I mean, doesn't the class A have a blank constructor in both cases ? If so, why isn't it working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the superclass has only constructors with args, you need to explicitly make an call to your superclass's constructor from your subclass, like below.

```
public B() {
    super(2);// passing an int value to your super class cons
}
```

> doesn't the class A have a blank constructor in both cases?

No. If you declare a constructor then the compiler will not include a default constructor, thus your `class A` doesn't have a default no-args constructor in case 2, and you have to explicitly make a super call from your sub class constructor.